# How to make an item not visible in Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to make one text item not visible. In properties I have not found this function, I resize text item to very small size but it is still visible.

I can't delete the item because I need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is to use the item's Visible property.

Not sure what version of Oracle Forms you are using but using 10.1.2.0.2, here is a form based on the EMP table. Note that the first field, Empno is shown.

[image]

Within Form Builder, select the item, empno, and bring up the Property Pallet (right click and select "Property Pallet" or use F4). Scroll through the list and look for the Visible property (or start typing Visible in the Property Pallet Search bar)

Change the value to No.

[image]

When the Form run again, the Empno Field is no longer displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the proposed and correct answer, if you have a lot of items hidden is better to also set the canvas to null in order to instruct the engine not to redraw them. For one item only it makes no sense but if this screen has many hidden items, and is heavily used on top of slow networks it can make a considerable difference in performance.